# Marmalade Sdk Gui not found

Tags: android, ios, marmalade

I'm new mobile game developer on Marmalade SDK.I have a game example made by Marmalade.When try to run it I'm getting this error.Pls help!

http://s4.postimage.org/c58430drx/Capture.png

Answer (score 0):

It suggests that you've included a subproject named GUI, but marmalade can't find it. Post the MKB's content in the question to identify the problem.